# How can I do 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-insert, primary-key, unique-constraint

I started by googling and found the article *[How to write INSERT if NOT EXISTS queries in standard SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/)* which talks about mutex tables.

I have a table with ~14 million records. If I want to add more data in the same format, is there a way to ensure the record I want to insert does not already exist **without using a pair of queries** (i.e., one query to check and one to insert is the result set is empty)?

Does a `unique` constraint on a field guarantee the `insert` will fail if it's already there?

It seems that with *merely* a constraint, when I issue the insert via PHP, the script croaks.

Answer (score 1011, accepted):

Use `INSERT IGNORE INTO table`.

There's also `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax, and you can find explanations in *[13.2.6.2 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)*.

---

**Post from [bogdan.org.ua](https://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html) according to [Google's webcache](https://web.archive.org/web/20191028155933/http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html):**

> 18th October 2007
>
> To start: as of the latest MySQL, syntax presented in the title is not
> possible. But there are several very easy ways to accomplish what is
> expected using existing functionality.
>
> There are 3 possible solutions: using INSERT IGNORE, REPLACE, or
> INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.
>
> Imagine we have a table:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `transcripts` (
> `ensembl_transcript_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
> `transcript_chrom_start` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
> `transcript_chrom_end` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (`ensembl_transcript_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
> ```
>
> Now imagine that we have an automatic pipeline importing transcripts
> meta-data from Ensembl, and that due to various reasons the pipeline
> might be broken at any step of execution. Thus, we need to ensure two
> things:

> 1. repeated executions of the pipeline will not destroy our
>    > database

> 2. repeated executions will not die due to ‘duplicate
>    > primary key’ errors.
>
> **Method 1: using REPLACE**
>
> It’s very simple:
>
> ```
> REPLACE INTO `transcripts`
> SET `ensembl_transcript_id` = 'ENSORGT00000000001',
> `transcript_chrom_start` = 12345,
> `transcript_chrom_end` = 12678;
> ```
>
> If the record exists, it will be overwritten; if it does not yet
> exist, it will be created. However, using this method isn’t efficient
> for our case: we do not need to overwrite existing records, it’s fine
> just to skip them.
>
> **Method 2: using INSERT IGNORE Also very simple:**
>
> ```
> INSERT IGNORE INTO `transcripts`
> SET `ensembl_transcript_id` = 'ENSORGT00000000001',
> `transcript_chrom_start` = 12345,
> `transcript_chrom_end` = 12678;
> ```
>
> Here, if the ‘ensembl_transcript_id’ is already present in the
> database, it will be silently skipped (ignored). (To be more precise,
> here’s a quote from MySQL reference manual: “If you use the IGNORE
> keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are
> treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
> duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
> causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted.”.) If the
> record doesn’t yet exist, it will be created.
>
> This second method has several potential weaknesses, including
> non-abortion of the query in case any other problem occurs (see the
> manual). Thus it should be used if previously tested without the
> IGNORE keyword.
>
> **Method 3: using INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:**
>
> Third option is to use `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
> syntax, and in the UPDATE part just do nothing do some meaningless
> (empty) operation, like calculating 0+0 (Geoffray suggests doing the
> id=id assignment for the MySQL optimization engine to ignore this
> operation). Advantage of this method is that it only ignores duplicate
> key events, and still aborts on other errors.
>
> As a final notice: this post was inspired by Xaprb. I’d also advise to
> consult his other post on writing flexible SQL queries.

Comment: and can I combine that with "delayed" to speed the script up?

Comment: yes, insert delayed might speed up things for you. try it out

Comment: update - I did an `insert ignore delay` and the php script finishes *much* faster by offloading all of the work onto mysql; for my current purposes, this is perfect; thanks

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind that [REPLACE INTO does DELETE _then_ INSERT, not UPDATE](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice)

Comment: So, which one is best -- INSERT IGNORE INTO table or INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?

Comment: @Jimmy: that depends entirely depends on what you want to achieve, they do different things.

Comment: `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is better since it does not delete the row, preserving any `auto_increment` columns and other data.

Comment: Where would you put in the `WHERE` statement if you want a specific condition to affect both INSERT and UPDATE?

Comment: @user1166877: What `WHERE` condition? There is no where condition in an INSERT statement

Comment: Just to inform everyone. Using `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` method does increment any AUTO_INCREMENT column with failed insert. Probably because it's not really failed, but UPDATE'd.

Comment: @user1147688 the same happens with `INSERT IGNORE`, this only applies to the InnoDB engine

Comment: Getting odd incremental behaviour using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY on InnoDB engine. The auto-increment column increments even on failed inserts. So if you had Keyword1,Keyword2 already stored and then tried to add a new one, Keyword3, Keyword3's ID would actually be incremented by 3, because of the previous duplicate finds/fails.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! I will be using the "on duplicate key update" option.

Comment: All of that works only if the table has a unique index. There may be reasons to insert rows with the same index, and then this query is useless, it still creates new rows.

Comment: How does this advice hold up today? Is "on duplicate key update" still sound advice?

Comment: The INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName works, if the colum you going to affect had a Unique key. That way its now going to insert it into the dbase and going to warn you about it, but will insert the rest.

Comment: is there a way to get the id of existing row after calling INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ? I was using $db->lastInsertId() when using auto_increment, but that's no longer valid if I use this instead, right?

Comment: @Myoch I'm not aware of an option to combine the two.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE works but note it ignores ALL errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920619/735926

Answer (score 329):

**Solution:**

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`value1`, `value2`) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` 
      WHERE `value1`='stuff for value1' AND `value2`='stuff for value2' LIMIT 1)
```

**Explanation:**

The innermost query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
      WHERE `value1`='stuff for value1' AND `value2`='stuff for value2' LIMIT 1
```

used as the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`-condition detects if there already exists a row with the data to be inserted. After one row of this kind is found, the query may stop, hence the `LIMIT 1` (micro-optimization, may be omitted).

The intermediate query

```
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM DUAL
```

represents the values to be inserted. `DUAL` refers to a special one row, one column table present by default in all Oracle databases (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table). On a MySQL-Server version 5.7.26 I got a valid query when omitting `FROM DUAL`, but older versions (like 5.5.60) seem to require the `FROM` information. By using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` the intermediate query returns an empty result set if the innermost query found matching data.

The outer query

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`value1`, `value2`)
```

inserts the data, if any is returned by the intermediate query.

Comment: can you give some more info on how to use this?

Comment: This variant is suitable if no unique key on table exists (`INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` require unique key constraints)

Comment: What if `stuff for value1` and `stuff for value2` are identical? This would throw a `Duplicate column name`

Comment: @Robin They aren't column names, they are strings; the columns are value1 and value2. This data for different columns of course contain dupes.

Comment: I also much prefer `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *` in the subqueries. Much more likely that this can be satisfied by an index.

Comment: @Robin use "AS v1" to solve "duplicate column name", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table#comment33044636_3164741

Comment: Instead of DUAL you can use (at least in mysql)     INSERT INTO `table` (value1, value2) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM (select 1) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` 
      WHERE value1='stuff for value1' AND value2='stuff for value2');

Comment: Thanks, that's the best solution in this topic, and it works ;-)

Comment: "FROM" is not required for a SELECT statement, you don't need it if you aren't using any columns from that table "FROM DUAL" is pointless

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and alternative solution to needing to update where a non unique key doesn't exist. Learned something new today!

Comment: Where are the VALUES to be inserted?

Answer (score 73):

In MySQL, [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) can be viable solutions.

---

**An example of [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) update based on mysql.com**:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

---

**An example of [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) based on mysql.com**

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Or:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Or:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

Answer (score 27):

Any simple constraint should do the job, if an exception is acceptable. Examples:

- primary key if not surrogate
- unique constraint on a column
- multi-column unique constraint

Sorry if this seems deceptively simple. I know it looks bad confronted to the link you share with us. ;-(

But I nevertheless give this answer, because it seems to fill your need. (If not, it may trigger you updating your requirements, which would be "a Good Thing"(TM) also).

If an insert would break the database unique constraint, an exception is throw at the database level, relayed by the driver. It will certainly stop your script, with a failure. It must be possible in PHP to address that case...

Comment: i added a clarification to the question - does your answer still apply?

Comment: I believe it does. A unique constraint will cause the failure of incorrect inserts. Note : you have to deal with this failure in your code, but this is quite standard.

Comment: for now I'm going to stick with the solution I accepted - but will further look into handling INSERT failures etc as the app grows

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` basically changes all errors into warnings so that your script is not interrupted.  You can then view any warnings with the command `SHOW WARNINGS`.  And another **important note**: UNIQUE constraints don't work with NULL values, ie. row1 (1, NULL) and row2 (1, NULL) will both get inserted (unless another constraint such as a primary key is broken). Unfortunate.

Answer (score 25):

Try the following:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM beta WHERE name = 'John' > 0)
  UPDATE alfa SET c1=(SELECT id FROM beta WHERE name = 'John')
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO beta (name) VALUES ('John')
  INSERT INTO alfa (c1) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID())
END
```

Comment: _Try This_ answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please edit this answer to include how the solution works and why it is a good idea.

Comment: Perfect solution in case the to-be-matching fields aren't keys ..!

Answer (score 18):

Here is a PHP function that will insert a row only if all the specified columns values don't already exist in the table.

- If one of the columns differ, the row will be added.
- If the table is empty, the row will be added.
- If a row exists where all the specified columns have the specified values, the row won't be added.

  ```
   function insert_unique($table, $vars)
   {
     if (count($vars)) {
       $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
       $vars = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $vars);

       $req = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`". join('`, `', array_keys($vars)) ."`) ";
       $req .= "SELECT '". join("', '", $vars) ."' FROM DUAL ";
       $req .= "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `$table` WHERE ";

       foreach ($vars AS $col => $val)
         $req .= "`$col`='$val' AND ";

       $req = substr($req, 0, -5) . ") LIMIT 1";

       $res = mysql_query($req) OR die();
       return mysql_insert_id();
     }
     return False;
   }
  ```

Example usage:

```
<?php
  insert_unique('mytable', array(
    'mycolumn1' => 'myvalue1',
    'mycolumn2' => 'myvalue2',
    'mycolumn3' => 'myvalue3'
    )
  );
?>
```

Comment: Pretty expensive if you have a huge load of insertions.

Comment: true, but efficient if you need to add specific checkups

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: What's the point in doing mysql_real_escape_string($table)?

Answer (score 18):

```
REPLACE INTO `transcripts`
SET `ensembl_transcript_id` = 'ENSORGT00000000001',
`transcript_chrom_start` = 12345,
`transcript_chrom_end` = 12678;
```

If the record exists, it will be overwritten; if it does not yet exist, it will be created.

Comment: `REPLACE` may delete the row and then insert instead of update. The side effect is that constraints may delete other objects and delete triggers are fired.

Comment: From the MySQL manual: "REPLACE makes sense only if a table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index. Otherwise, it becomes equivalent to INSERT, because there is no index to be used to determine whether a new row duplicates another."

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` is, perhaps, the ***worst*** possible answer to this question

Answer (score 9):

There are several answers that cover how to solve this if you have a `UNIQUE` index that you can check against with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `INSERT IGNORE`. That is not always the case, and as `UNIQUE` has a length constraint (1000 bytes) you might not be able to change that. For example, I had to work with metadata in [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) (`wp_postmeta`).

I finally solved it with two queries:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = ? WHERE meta_key = ? AND post_id = ?;
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) SELECT DISTINCT ?, ?, ? FROM wp_postmeta WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = ? AND post_id = ?);
```

Query 1 is a regular `UPDATE` query without any effect when the data set in question is not there. Query 2 is an `INSERT` which depends on a `NOT EXISTS`, i.e. the `INSERT` is only executed when the data set doesn't exist.

Comment: This example works is a bit wrong. 
It will insert the duplicate rows as many there exists in the table `meta_key`. If adding `LIMIT 1` at the end - it will work, but still this feels kid of unsafe/hacky. I prefer the select part after insert write like this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ?, ?, ?) as tmp` - it feels safer in case if forgot to write `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 5):

Something worth noting is that INSERT IGNORE will still increment the primary key whether the statement was a success or not just like a normal INSERT would.

This will cause gaps in your primary keys that might make a programmer mentally unstable. Or if your application is poorly designed and depends on perfect incremental primary keys, it might become a headache.

Look into `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` (server setting, and comes with a slight performance hit), or use a SELECT first to make sure your query will not fail (which also comes with a performance hit and extra code).

Comment: Why would "gaps in your primary keys" - even potentially - "make a programmer mentally unstable"? Gaps occur all the time in primary keys - every time you delete a record, for example.

Comment: Starting with a `SELECT` defeats the whole purpose of just handing-off a big batch of `INSERT`s and not wanting to worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

### Update or insert without known primary key

If you already have a unique or primary key, the other answers with either `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` or `REPLACE INTO ...` should work fine (note that replace into deletes if exists and then inserts - thus does not partially update existing values).

But if you have the values for `some_column_id` and `some_type`, the combination of which are known to be unique. And you want to update `some_value` if exists, or insert if not exists. And you want to do it in just one query (to avoid using a transaction). This might be a solution:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table (id, some_column_id, some_type, some_value)
SELECT t.id, t.some_column_id, t.some_type, t.some_value
FROM (
    SELECT id, some_column_id, some_type, some_value
    FROM my_table
    WHERE some_column_id = ? AND some_type = ?
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.id, s.some_column_id, s.some_type, s.some_value
    FROM (SELECT NULL AS id, ? AS some_column_id, ? AS some_type, ? AS some_value) AS s
) AS t
LIMIT 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
some_value = ?
```

Basically, the query executes this way (less complicated than it may look):

- Select an existing row via the `WHERE` clause match.
- Union that result with a potential new row (table `s`), where the column values are explicitly given (s.id is NULL, so it will generate a new auto-increment identifier).
- If an existing row is found, then the potential new row from table `s` is discarded (due to LIMIT 1 on table `t`), and it will always trigger an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` which will `UPDATE` the `some_value` column.
- If an existing row is not found, then the potential new row is inserted (as given by table `s`).

*Note: Every table in a relational database should have at least a primary auto-increment `id` column. If you don't have this, add it, even when you don't need it at first sight. It is definitely needed for this "trick".*

Comment: Several other answerers have proffered an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` format. Why did you also?

Comment: @warren Either you did not read my answer, you do not understand it, or I didn't explain it properly. In any case, let me emphasize the following: this is not just a regular `INSERT INTO... SELECT FROM...` solution. Please refer to me a link to an answer that is the same, if you can find it I will delete this answer, otherwise you upvote my answer (deal?). Be sure to verify that the answer you're going to link only uses 1 query (for update+insert), no transaction, and is able to target any combination of columns that are known to be unique (so separately the columns don't need to be unique).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support the [`MERGE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) statement otherwise that would have been the most versatile solution. The `INSERT IGNORE` hack requires unique key constraints which is not always an option.

A simple solution is to use table value constructor along with `not exists`. This allows you to insert multiple rows with customized duplicate checking. And there is no repetition in the where clause.

The following is the syntax for MySQL, but the logic works in any RDBMS that supports table value constructors:

```
insert into tbl (k, a, b)
select k, a, b
from (values
    row(3, 'a3', 'b3'),
    row(4, 'a4', 'b4'),
    row(5, 'a5', 'b5')
) as tvc(k, a, b)
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tbl
    where tbl.k = tvc.k
)
```

DB<>Fiddle for [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/XXYwhC7k), [MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/EnDTsbrq), [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/ja9vfSi-)

Comment: how is this better/different from what has already been answered hereon?

Comment: I didn't see any example of inserting multiple rows or one using tvc.

Comment: @warren are you asking for the answer to give explicit, compelling insights regarding why this answer should be used over pre-existing advice?

Comment: @mickmackusa - with a new answer to such a prominent question, yes: that's precisely what I am asking. Why is this answer better-than/adding-to what has already been answered

Comment: @SalmanA ... the accepted answer covers multiple rows quite handily - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361368/4418 :)

Comment: The accepted answer requires unique keys, not ideal when you have specific or one time need. I'll expand my answer in a while.

Answer (score -2):

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (columns) VALUES (values) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the accepted answer, and all the previously-supplied and -upvoted responses?

Comment: @warren  The biggest difference is that this answer won't work in MySQL.  It would work in PostgreSQL and potentially other database software that support `ON CONFLICT` (albeit not in SQLite, which would `IGNORE` rather than `DO NOTHING`).

Comment: This works in postgresql, IGNORE did not.

Comment: @mdfst13 - if it "won't work in MySQL", then it;s *doubly-bad* in a question *about MySQL*!