# Using knexjs for insert ignore

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

I'm having this issue, I have a set of data I want to insert using knexjs. But I want the insertion to ignore duplicate, i.e only insert if data does not exist. I can do this

`knex('rates').insert(allRates);`

but I was wondering who I can use the `ignore` modifier if it exists. I also don't want to do `knex.raw`
Thank you.

Comment: correct formatting required

Comment: why the aversion to `raw`? it is part of knex for a reason. Can we use raw to express the data as a set to select from or join against?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, thought of using [this reasoning here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011170/2405689)  is it a good practise?

Answer (score 18):

Knex.js does not provide this functionality.
A potential solution is:

```
knex.raw(knex('rates').insert(allRates).toString().replace('insert', 'INSERT IGNORE'));
```

It's minimum usage of the `raw` function, and doesn't force you to convert data manually.

Answer (score 18):

Its 2021. There's now a solution to this using Knex.

```js
knex('tableName')
  .insert({
    email: "ignore@example.com",
    name: "John Doe"
  })
  .onConflict('email')
  .ignore()
//Outputs: insert ignore into `tableName` (`email`, `name`) values ('ignore@example.com', 'John Doe')
```

[Docs reference](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#onconflict)

Answer (score -2):

I do it the following way:

```
knex_insert_ignore(knex, 'rates', allRates);

// insert into `metric_names` (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) values (1, 2, DEFAULT, DEFAULT), (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 3, 4)
// INSERT IGNORE `metric_names` (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) values (1, 2, DEFAULT, DEFAULT), (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 3, 4)
function knex_insert_ignore(knex, table, rows)
{
    if (rows.length == 0) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    const keys = rows_keys(rows);
    const inserts = [];
    const bindings = [table, ...keys];
    for (let i = 0, end = rows.length; i < end; ++i) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const insert = [];
        for (let j = 0, jj = keys.length; j < jj; ++j) {
            const key = keys[j];
            if (row[key] === undefined) {
                insert.push('DEFAULT');
            }
            else {
                insert.push('?');
                bindings.push(row[key]);
            }
        }
        inserts.push(`(${insert})`);
    }
    return knex.raw(`INSERT IGNORE INTO ?? (${keys.slice().fill('??')}) VALUES ${inserts}`, bindings);
}

// Return all keys mentioned in rows
function rows_keys(rows)
{
    const unique = {};
    for (let i = 0, end = rows.length; i < end; ++i) {
        const keys = Object.keys(rows[i]);
        for (let j = 0, jj = keys.length; j < jj; ++j) {
            unique[keys[j]] = true;
        }
    }
    return Object.keys(unique);
}
```