# which of 2 queries has better prformance?

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-redshift

Trying to compare 2 queries to understand which one would be faster. Basic idea is to have 1 table ( say `test1`) that has no duplicates.  Then you trying to insert only delta from second table (say `test2`) in such a way that if second table has duplicates, then only 1 copy of the record is inserted.

#### Prep:

```
create table test1  (id varchar(10), a bigint, b bigint);
create table test2  (id varchar(10), a bigint, b bigint);
insert into test1 values ('aaa', 1, 1), ('aa2', 1, 2), ('aa3', 1, 3);
insert into test1 values ('bbb', 2, 1), ('bb2', 2, 2);
insert into test1 values ('bbb', 2, 1), ('bb2', 2, 2);
insert into test2 values ('aaa', 1, 1), ('aa2', 1, 2), ('aa3', 1, 3);
```

#### Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO test2
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                a,
                b
FROM   test1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   test2
                   WHERE  test2.id = test1.id);
```

#### Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO test2
    SELECT id,
           a,
           b
    FROM   (SELECT t2.*
            FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY id) AS dup_id,
                           *
                    FROM   test1) t2
            WHERE  t2.dup_id = 1) t1
    WHERE  t1.id NOT IN (SELECT test2.id
                         FROM   test2);
```

Can someone help me understand which one would be faster and more efficient?

#### Update

Explain of the 1-st query:

```
db=# explain insert into test2 select distinct id, a, b from test1 where not exists (select * from test2 where test2.id=test1.id);                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT*"  (cost=3613333.97..4213334.30 rows=7 width=49)
   ->  XN Unique  (cost=3613333.97..4213334.23 rows=7 width=49)
         ->  XN Hash Left Join DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=3613333.97..4213334.18 rows=7 width=49)
               Hash Cond: ("outer".oid = "inner".oid)
               Filter: ("inner".oid IS NULL)
               ->  XN Seq Scan on test1  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=7 width=53)
               ->  XN Hash  (cost=3613333.96..3613333.96 rows=5 width=4)
                     ->  XN Subquery Scan volt_dt_1  (cost=1760000.36..3613333.96 rows=5 width=4)
                           ->  XN Unique  (cost=1760000.36..3613333.91 rows=5 width=4)
                                 ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_BOTH  (cost=1760000.36..3613333.90 rows=5 width=4)
                                       Outer Dist Key: test1.id
                                       Inner Dist Key: volt_dt_2.id
                                       Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".id)::text)
                                       ->  XN Seq Scan on test1  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=7 width=37)
                                       ->  XN Hash  (cost=1760000.34..1760000.34 rows=5 width=33)
                                             ->  XN Subquery Scan volt_dt_2  (cost=1760000.29..1760000.34 rows=5 width=33)
                                                   ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=1760000.29..1760000.29 rows=5 width=33)
                                                         ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_BOTH  (cost=0.06..1760000.27 rows=5 width=33)
                                                               Outer Dist Key: test1.id
                                                               Inner Dist Key: test2.id
                                                               Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".id)::text)
                                                               ->  XN Seq Scan on test1  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=7 width=33)
                                                               ->  XN Hash  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=5 width=33)
                                                                     ->  XN Seq Scan on test2  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=5 width=33)
 ----- Tables missing statistics: test2, test1 -----
 ----- Update statistics by running the ANALYZE command on these tables -----
(26 rows)
```

Explain of the second query

```
db=# explain insert into test2 select id, a, b from (select t2.* from ( select row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as dup_id, * from test1 ) t2 where t2.dup_id = 1 ) t1 where t1.id not in (select test2.id from test2); 
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 XN Hash NOT IN Join DS_DIST_INNER  (cost=1000000000000.23..999999999999999967336168804116691273849533185806555472917961779471295845921727862608739868455469056.00 rows=1 width=49)
   Inner Dist Key: db.test2.id
   Hash Cond: (("outer".id)::text = ("inner".id)::text)
   ->  XN Subquery Scan t2  (cost=1000000000000.17..1000000000000.36 rows=1 width=49)
         Filter: (dup_id = 1)
         ->  XN Window  (cost=1000000000000.17..1000000000000.27 rows=7 width=49)
               Partition: id
               Order: id
               ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000000000000.17..1000000000000.19 rows=7 width=49)
                     Sort Key: id
                     ->  XN Network  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=7 width=49)
                           Distribute
                           ->  XN Seq Scan on test1  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=7 width=49)
   ->  XN Hash  (cost=0.05..0.05 rows=5 width=33)
         ->  XN Seq Scan on test2  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=5 width=33)
 ----- Tables missing statistics: test2, test1 -----
 ----- Update statistics by running the ANALYZE command on these tables -----
(17 rows)
```

Comment: try explain or explain analyze

Comment: **First**. Why dont you try it and check explain plan? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. **Second** Postgre 9.5+ has already one solution implemented check [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009584/how-to-emulate-insert-ignore-and-on-duplicate-key-update-sql-merge-with-po/34639631#34639631)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank a lot for the link, didn't know about that. But unfortunately Im running it on postgres which is a fork of 8.x postgres ....

Comment: @Vor Yes i have the same kind of problem right now and also couldnt use it because Im 9.3... but if you check related links to that questions you will see lof of solutions. Warning Is a long path ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think first should be faster, although it wants an index on `test2(id)`.

Normally, the answer to such questions is "try it on your data and your system . . . and let us know".  However, the `row_number()` requires a full scan of `table1`.  You might as well do the index lookup in `table2` at the same time -- which is the first version.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone knows INSERT is always expensive comparing to SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE since the INSERT doesn't have WHERE clauses and also more expensive when we have more indexes in a table.

Still both the query is doing an INSERT. So, my above point is not valid.

1. In your first query, DISTINCT definitely needs a Table scan, and in the WHERE clause instead of NOT EXISTS, you can check the ID with the NOT IN operator

**INSERT INTO test2

SELECT DISTINCT id,

                a,

                b

FROM   test1

WHERE  id NOT IN  (SELECT id FROM   test2);**

As Everyone knows, SELECT * FROM Table is expensive, better to use required attributes.

2. In your second query, As Gordon said, ROW_NUMBER needs a table scan too and you are using **lots of derived tables** in that query, so i guess the first query is optimized than the second.