# Postgresq/Python, turn an update and an insert queries into one query, which inserts only if record doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am using the following two queries (in PostgreSQL/Python):

```
query_update = """UPDATE my_table
               SET {}='{}'
               WHERE index={}""".format(*[str(updated_columns), str(updated_values), str(updated_row_indices)])

query_insert = """INSERT INTO my_table ({})
                   VALUES ('{}')""".format(*[str(updated_columns), str(updated_values), str(updated_row_indices)])
```

Instead of these two queries, I want to have only one query that will automatically insert record if it doesn't exits. I have two questions:

1. How to make these two queries into one query using PostgreSQL? (important)
2. How to do the same using MySQL? (optional)

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639631/1207049

Comment: I saw that, but I couldn't make it work using my example.

Answer (score 1):

*query_update* is not needed.

Add ***ON CONFLICT*** clause to you *query_insert* variable.

```
query_insert = """INSERT INTO my_table ({})
                   VALUES ('{}')
ON CONFLICT ({}) DO
UPDATE
   SET {}""".format(*[str(columns_to_insert), str(column_values), str(key_columns)], str(column_values_update))
```

Here, 
*columns_to_insert* should be a comma separated list of columns you insert data to;
*column_values* should be a comma separated list of values for *columns_to_insert*;
*key_columns* should be a comma separated list of primary key columns;
*column_values_update* should be a comma separated list of *column_name=column_value* pairs (similar to regular UPDATE command).

Comment: Thank you! One question, since I have a Pandas DataFrame, do I put `df.columns` instead of `<unique key columns>`?

Comment: @user8436761 Sorry, don't know what df.columns is... Instead of <unique key columns>, you should type the comma separated list of my_table primary key columns.

Comment: That would be one column called 'index', but when I put it in, I am getting an error: `SET {}='{}'""".format(*[str(updated_columns), str(updated_values), str(updated_row_indices)])
IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Any ideas?

Comment: @user8436761 Ok, I've edited the answer and added some explanations. Attention: I've changed the names of your variables and added some new ones. The number of {} pairs must be equal to number of items you pass in the array for format function. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried multiple versions, but I am still either getting the same tuple index out of range error or `ERROR:  source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression` error. Do you have an example with some column names and real values how would the query look like?

Comment: I have been trying somethign like this in a terminal but I am getting the above subselect or ROW() error: `INSERT INTO my_table (index, col_name_1, col_name_5) VALUES (4,'value for col 1', 'value for col 5') ON CONFLICT (index) DO UPDATE SET (index)=4, (col_name_1)='value for col 1', (col_name_2)=('value for col 5');`

Comment: @user8436761 In your code, everything looks ok except UPDATE clause. Why do you use brackets there? I recommend you to read about UPDATE syntax in SQL. This part should look like this: DO UPDATE SET index=4, col_name_1='value for col 1', col_name_2='value for col 5'

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a merge statement. This will do exactly what you are looking for

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

Comment: Do you know how to turn the above code into a merge statement?

Comment: My understanding is that merge has issues with concurrency, which means you usually want to lock the table when using it, which is suboptimal for updating a single row.

Also merge is primarily designed for updating many rows in a single statement. For OP's purpose, upsert (ON CONFLICT) is more appropriate.